# Galaxy Tab Multi Device App Installation

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-tab, installation, automation, multiple-devices

I am planning on having a few labs of Galaxy Tabs (60+ tabs), and I need a way to manage all of these. Primarily I need a way to automatically install apps on all of these at once. I know there is a solution called Meraki but it won't install the apps for you it just sends a notification and the user has to install individually install the app which is kinda useless.

Comment: This could be possible from the command line, using SSH, but would require additional knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

[Mobile Device Manager](http://www.mobiledevicemanager.com/) might be a solution for you. You can find an introduction with screenshots and more [on AndroidTapp](http://www.androidtapp.com/how-to-remotely-mass-deploy-android-apps-to-devices/). Quoting:

> 3CX Mobile Device Manager is a flexible and easy to implement service that allows a user to remotely manage, locate and administrate mobile devices. From the comfort of a web browser you can control multiple devices in a variety of ways. It’s a great option for network administrators who, in addition to swathes of desktop PCs and laptops to worry about, now also has to ensure the company’s smartphones and tablets are secure and up to date.