# Automated deployment of app to multiple devices

Tags: multiple-devices

I have a business android app and I need to deploy it to 2000 android devices. Is there an automated way to do this? Can I deploy my app, install a widget app from google play and configure it in an automated and tested way? Coming from a web background I'm thinking of something like web deploy. [Octopus deploy](http://octopusdeploy.com/) for example.

(all devices are 4.1.2)

Comment: Are all these devices owned by the company that your business app is for? IF so this sounds like a job for Mobile Device Management Software. Many of them allow an administrator to specify apps that should be installed on all of the managed devices. See some of these previous questions: [Which program allows remote management of Android devices?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56857/) or [Galaxy Tab Multi Device App Installation](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32049/)

Comment: thanks for your reply. I came across that before but at a $17,500 pricetag it's a big no. it seems like a good management tool but too much for what I need. I just need a one time deployment. Don't need to track or manage what apps are installed. but thanks anyway.

Comment: No, sorry. In the end we had an external team doing the tedious work of deploying the app on each device. We've added an Update function on the app that pointed to a remote repository of apks.
There are paid solutions out there. but I think that on all of them you need to install something manually on each device first...

Answer (score 0):

Zebra devices use a program to serve and deploy smartphone apps, called StageNow

You can connect to your devices wirelessly through the same network using the adb from android studio, once connected install the app with an adb command

there should be more options provided by the official android team, in my opinion, some times they treat android developers as if they were all hobbyists, i deploy apps for production in a factory, we use StageNow which allow rapid deployment